# Clusterless AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server

I was trying my hands on Clusterless AlwaysON for SQL Server 2017 and missed to keep the Cluster Type as None while configuring.

Right now it is set to External and I can't test failover.

Is there any possibility to change the Cluster Type to 'None', or do I need to re-configure?

Comment: Delete the AG and start over.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Ahh I wish there was an easier way. Just thought to check before doing that. thanks Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't Alter that state. You have to re-config the AlwaysOn with option None.